# nodejs http_incomingmessage's query attribute is not null, so express can't parse query parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using node 6.9.4 and express 4, when nodejs _http_common.js create the IncomingMessage(line num: 60), the parser.incoming.query will be a function(normally it's undefined), so express can's parse the request object's query parameter

express\lib\middleware\query.js(line 38):

```
return function query(req, res, next){
    if (!req.query) {
      var val = parseUrl(req).query;
      req.query = queryparse(val, opts);
    } 

    next();
  };
```

parser.incoming.query:

```
function getQuery() { … }
length:0
name:"getQuery"
prototype:getQuery {constructor: function getQuery() { … }}
__proto__:function () {}
```

Comment: the 'query' exists on parser.incoming's prototype, but i didn't find any 'query' keyword in _stream_readable.js and _http_incoming.js

Answer (score 0):

resolved, it's because of restify 5.0, it will override request object to make req.query to be a function, so express can't parse the query parameter

Comment: Why are you using Express if you're also using Restify?

Comment: @robertklep I don't need restify, but I need bpmn, it will require 'restify'

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier then to stick with Restify instead of using Express? Both frameworks are pretty similar, and running both together may lead to more issues.

Comment: @robertklep it's a big project which started at 2014, need to spend a huge effort if changing the structure of the app. Seems I shouldn't choose bpmn package to develop my work-flow